# Issue with assembly creation

Tags: maven-2

In my project, I m creating many assemblies(4-5) and they are output to target.1/2 of these assemblies are not taking their final names(or assembly id) , but as per the format artifactID-version.jar..This is very confusing
Why is this so?

Extracts from my pom.xml --

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.apple</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
  <name>maven_XX</name>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>  


  <build>
    <plugins>
    <!-- Added to avoid the compilation issue wrt Annotations -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
        <executions>              
          <execution>
            <id>clientjar</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>XX_client</finalName>
              <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>
                  ${basedir}/src/main/resources/assemblies/clientjar.xml
                </descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>11***</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>11server</finalName>
              <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>
                  ${basedir}/src/main/resources/assemblies/11server.xml
                </descriptor>
              </descriptors>
              <outputDirectory>assemblies-target</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>cache</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>cache</finalName>
              <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>
                 ${basedir}/src/main/resources/assemblies/cache.xml
              </descriptor>
              </descriptors>
              <outputDirectory>assemblies-target</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
```

Comment: Its is not random.specific assemblies are not following.
Expected output for each is jar with provided final name.
But i m getting them as - Project name-version.jar

Answer (score 14):

Pulling [Lyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80144/lyle)'s comment out to the question level to provide visibility.

While the previous answer works [Lyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80144/lyle) points out that:

> If I understand this correctly, it seems like a somewhat invasive workaround for what amounts to a bug in the assembly plugin. Instead, try setting false in the configuration. See: [MASSEMBLY-352](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-352?jql=project%20%3D%20MASSEMBLY)

For artifacts that are not attached to the repository distribution this is a fine solution and worked well for me.

```
...
<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
<attach>false</attach>
...
```

Comment: Works fine for a "single assembly" project.

Answer (score 8):

When you run the assembly, do you see something like this output to the console by Maven?:

```
[INFO] [assembly:single {execution: 11***}]
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: C:\test\test-parent2/src/main/resources/assemblies/11server.xml
[INFO] Building jar: C:\test\test-parent2\assemblies-target\11server.jar
[WARNING] Configuration options: 'appendAssemblyId' is set to false, and 'classifier' is missing.
Instead of attaching the assembly file: C:\test\test-parent2\assemblies-target\11server.jar, it will become the file for
 main project artifact.
NOTE: If multiple descriptors or descriptor-formats are provided for this project, the value of this file will be non-de
terministic!
```

This happens because all your assemblies specify `<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>` and no classifier is specified. The classifier is deprecated in the 2.2-beta-4 version so is ignored anyway, this is a bug/feature in the plugin.
As a result, Maven will always make one of the assemblies the "main" artifact for jar packaging, and you don't see it in your target-assemblies directory.

To work around this you can specify that your project has `pom` packaging, then bind the goals for the jar lifecycle to the pom.

To enable the `process-resources` and `compile` goals you would change the packaging to `pom`, add the following configuration to your pom, and run the standard lifecycle goals. For example `mvn package` or `mvn install`.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>              
    <execution>
      <id>process-resources</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>resources</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>              
    <execution>
      <id>compile</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The full list of goals bound to the jar lifecycle can be found in the *Built in Lifecycle Bindings* section of the [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). They all follow a similar pattern to the `process-resources` and `compile` goals. In your case you probably want to omit the `jar` goal.

Comment: Hi
 When running the assembly, i m getting the warning as you have given.
So, u mean to say that i shud use goal=compile for the assemblies(which gives jars) and enable the maven compile goal ?

Comment: No I mean make the project's packaging "pom" and configure the plugins so that the goals normally executed in the jar's lifecycle are executed in the pom's lifecycle, with the configuration above the resources and compile plugins will be executed during the default lifecycle, so you still run `mvn install`. This gets round the bug in the assembly plugin

Comment: Hi..
I changed the packaging as "pom".Added the two plugins you have provided and didn't make any configuration changes to the assemblies.On running mvn install, for the 2nd assembly , it is giving-
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DuplicateArtifactAttachmentException: Duplicate artifact attachment detected.

Comment: there is no such configuration in your question, could you update the question to include it?

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DuplicateArtifactAttachmentException: Duplicate artifact attachment detected. (project: com.xxx:maven_XX:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT; illegal attachment: com.XXX:maven_XX:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)

Comment: Hi
i customised the goas as -preclean compile package and encountered the above error.But when i ran mvn preclean compile package form cmd line, the assemblies are getting created except one assembly which contains the test-classes.Please tell me why this behaviour

Comment: If I understand this correctly, it seems like a somewhat invasive workaround for what amounts to a bug in the assembly plugin. Instead, try setting <attach>false</attach> in the configuration. See: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-352